# spring-security-rest plugin logout failure

Tags: rest, grails, spring-security-rest

I am using **spring-security-rest:1.5.0.RC2** with Grails 2.5.0.  I created a controller for user profile information UserProfileController which extends RestfulController.  Login in works fine as well as retrieving a user profile.  However, when I try to \api\logout I get

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
```

When logging out I specify the Bearer token so it finds the user correctly, but it seems to want to use the static rules to determine if access to logout page is permitted and since it doesn't find the rule if concludes that access is denied.  This is due to pessimistic locking of pages introduced in the recent version of grails.  See log below.

```
2015-04-20 22:44:04,252 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  - Checking match of request : '/api/logout'; against '/api/**'
2015-04-20 22:44:04,252 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy  - /api/logout at position 1 of 7 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'MutableLogoutFilter'
2015-04-20 22:44:04,252 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy  - /api/logout at position 2 of 7 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RestAuthenticationFilter'
2015-04-20 22:44:04,252 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG rest.RestAuthenticationFilter  - Actual URI is /api/logout; endpoint URL is /api/login
2015-04-20 22:44:04,252 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy  - /api/logout at position 3 of 7 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
2015-04-20 22:44:04,253 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy  - /api/logout at position 4 of 7 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
2015-04-20 22:44:04,253 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter  - Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'grails.plugin.springsecurity.authentication.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationToken@dc4a600: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@dc730200: Username: __grails.anonymous.user__; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: false; AccountNonExpired: false; credentialsNonExpired: false; AccountNonLocked: false; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@0: RemoteIpAddress: fe80:0:0:0:414:abd0:23ec:bb74%10; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
2015-04-20 22:44:04,253 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy  - /api/logout at position 5 of 7 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RestTokenValidationFilter'
2015-04-20 22:44:04,253 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG bearer.BearerTokenReader  - Looking for bearer token in Authorization header, query string or Form-Encoded body parameter
2015-04-20 22:44:04,253 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG bearer.BearerTokenReader  - Found bearer token in Authorization header
2015-04-20 22:44:04,253 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG rest.RestTokenValidationFilter  - Token found: eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJleHAiOjE0Mjk1OTE0NDEsInN1YiI6InN3YXZlayIsInJvbGVzIjpbIlJPTEVfQURNSU4iLCJST0xFX1VTRVIiXSwiaWF0IjoxNDI5NTg3ODQxfQ.am7f4VaQgdRWyMzBvfyT_jAmxeOZPhlURaNjdxVS6rM
2015-04-20 22:44:04,253 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG rest.RestTokenValidationFilter  - Trying to authenticate the token
2015-04-20 22:44:04,254 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG rest.RestAuthenticationProvider  - Trying to validate token eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJleHAiOjE0Mjk1OTE0NDEsInN1YiI6InN3YXZlayIsInJvbGVzIjpbIlJPTEVfQURNSU4iLCJST0xFX1VTRVIiXSwiaWF0IjoxNDI5NTg3ODQxfQ.am7f4VaQgdRWyMzBvfyT_jAmxeOZPhlURaNjdxVS6rM
2015-04-20 22:44:04,254 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG rest.JwtService  - Parsed an HMAC signed JWT
2015-04-20 22:44:04,256 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG jwt.JwtTokenStorageService  - Successfully verified JWT
2015-04-20 22:44:04,256 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG rest.JwtService  - Parsed an HMAC signed JWT
2015-04-20 22:44:04,257 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG rest.RestAuthenticationProvider  - Now is Mon Apr 20 22:44:04 CDT 2015 and token expires at Mon Apr 20 23:44:01 CDT 2015
2015-04-20 22:44:04,257 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG rest.RestAuthenticationProvider  - Expiration: 56
2015-04-20 22:44:04,258 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG rest.RestAuthenticationProvider  - Authentication result: grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.AccessToken(accessToken:eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJleHAiOjE0Mjk1OTE0NDEsInN1YiI6InN3YXZlayIsInJvbGVzIjpbIlJPTEVfQURNSU4iLCJST0xFX1VTRVIiXSwiaWF0IjoxNDI5NTg3ODQxfQ.am7f4VaQgdRWyMzBvfyT_jAmxeOZPhlURaNjdxVS6rM, expiration:56, refreshToken:null, principal:org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@caf81bff: Username: swavek; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_USER, super:grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.AccessToken@31b92fe9: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@caf81bff: Username: swavek; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_USER; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_USER)
2015-04-20 22:44:04,258 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG rest.RestTokenValidationFilter  - Token authenticated. Storing the authentication result in the security context
2015-04-20 22:44:04,258 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG rest.RestTokenValidationFilter  - Authentication result: grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.AccessToken(accessToken:eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJleHAiOjE0Mjk1OTE0NDEsInN1YiI6InN3YXZlayIsInJvbGVzIjpbIlJPTEVfQURNSU4iLCJST0xFX1VTRVIiXSwiaWF0IjoxNDI5NTg3ODQxfQ.am7f4VaQgdRWyMzBvfyT_jAmxeOZPhlURaNjdxVS6rM, expiration:56, refreshToken:null, principal:org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@caf81bff: Username: swavek; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_USER, super:grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.AccessToken@31b92fe9: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@caf81bff: Username: swavek; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_USER; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_USER)
2015-04-20 22:44:04,259 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG rest.RestTokenValidationFilter  - Continuing the filter chain
2015-04-20 22:44:04,259 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy  - /api/logout at position 6 of 7 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
2015-04-20 22:44:04,259 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy  - /api/logout at position 7 of 7 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
2015-04-20 22:44:04,260 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor  - Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /api/logout; Attributes: [_DENY_]
2015-04-20 22:44:04,260 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor  - Previously Authenticated: grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.AccessToken(accessToken:eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJleHAiOjE0Mjk1OTE0NDEsInN1YiI6InN3YXZlayIsInJvbGVzIjpbIlJPTEVfQURNSU4iLCJST0xFX1VTRVIiXSwiaWF0IjoxNDI5NTg3ODQxfQ.am7f4VaQgdRWyMzBvfyT_jAmxeOZPhlURaNjdxVS6rM, expiration:56, refreshToken:null, principal:org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@caf81bff: Username: swavek; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_USER, super:grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.AccessToken@31b92fe9: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@caf81bff: Username: swavek; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_USER; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_USER)
2015-04-20 22:44:04,260 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG hierarchicalroles.RoleHierarchyImpl  - getReachableGrantedAuthorities() - From the roles [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_USER] one can reach [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_USER] in zero or more steps.
2015-04-20 22:44:04,261 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG access.ExceptionTranslationFilter  - Access is denied (user is not anonymous); delegating to AccessDeniedHandler
```

My controllerAnnotations.staticRules in Config.groovy don't specify any \api**

My filterChain.chainMap looks like this

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.filterChain.chainMap = [
    '/api/**': 'JOINED_FILTERS,-exceptionTranslationFilter,-authenticationProcessingFilter,-securityContextPersistenceFilter,-rememberMeAuthenticationFilter',  // Stateless chain
    '/**': 'JOINED_FILTERS,-restTokenValidationFilter,-restExceptionTranslationFilter'                                                                          // Traditional chain
]
```

What are the security annotations on the logout method of the controller implementing it?  How can I make this work?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the `RestLogoutFilter` is not in the chain. But even if it were, there is no logout feature when using JWT. Quoting the [documentation](http://alvarosanchez.github.io/grails-spring-security-rest/latest/docs/guide/authentication.html#logout):

> Logout is not possible when using [JWT](http://alvarosanchez.github.io/grails-spring-security-rest/latest/docs/guide/tokenStorage.html#jwt) tokens (the default strategy), as no state is kept in the server. If you still want to have logout, you can provide your own implementation by creating a subclass of [`JwtTokenStorageService`](http://alvarosanchez.github.io/grails-spring-security-rest/latest/docs/gapi/grails/plugin/springsecurity/rest/token/storage/jwt/JwtTokenStorageService.html) and overriding the methods `storeToken` and `removeToken`.
>   Then, register your implementation in `resources.groovy` as `tokenStorageService`.
>
> However, a more rational approach would be just to remove the token from the client (eg, browser's local storage) and let the tokens expire (they will expire anyway, unlike with other storages like Memcached or Redis where they get refreshed on every access).

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  I missed the fact that I am using JWT.  I see so the easiest way would be to null out the token on the client and not bother with contacting the server at /api/logout.